# RadMenu item selected should focus

Tags: asp.net, telerik, menuitem

I have Radmenu placed in master page  and if I click any item ,page will get post back so its difficult to maintain item selected focused with the color.I tried placing an ajaxpanel,still its getting post backed.

```
    <telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="RadAjaxPanel1" runat="server">

            <telerik:RadMenu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Skin="Office2010Silver"  
                Width="100%" Font-Bold="true"
                Visible ="false">
                <Items>
                  < <telerik:RadMenuItem runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Home.aspx"                              Text="Home">
                    </telerik:RadMenuItem>
                 </Items>
                        </telerik:RadMenu>
```

Any suggestions will be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to present some context to your users so that they know where they are in your application?

Consider the path + breadcrumb demo:  http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/menu/examples/programming/showpath/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code for Highlight Menu which is selected.

```
RadMenuItem currentItem = MainMenu.FindItemByUrl(Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
if (currentItem != null)
{
     currentItem.HighlightPath();
}
else
{
      MainMenu.Items[0].HighlightPath();
}
```